# How to filter the Different array inside the array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to **filter** only **active product** from the **array**.

```
var myArr = [
    [{
        product: "Test",
        price: 30, 
        active: true
    },
    {
        product: "Test2",
        price: 50, 
        active: true
    }],
    [{
        product: "Test3",
        price: 60, 
        active: false
    },
    {
        product: "Test4",
        price: 50, 
        active: true
    }]
    ]
```

What is the best practices to filter the active products?

Comment: Please add the expected output for this input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a nested array so you have to filter it twice based on `active == true`.

Please find the following solution:

```
var myArr = [
    [{
    product: "Test",
    price: 30, 
    active: true
    },
    {
    product: "Test2",
    price: 50, 
    active: true
    }],
    [{
    product: "Test3",
    price: 60, 
    active: false
    },
    {
    product: "Test4",
    price: 50, 
    active: true
    }]
    ];


    var newArray = [];

        myArr.filter(function (el) {
          el.filter(function(e2)
          {
            if(e2.active)
            {
              newArray.push(e2);
            }
          }); 
        });
    console.log(newArray);
```

You can also get the results by using the foreach

```
var newArray = [];
    myArr.forEach((val,key)=>{
      val.forEach((val1,key1)=>{
        if(val1.active)
        {
          newArray.push(val1);
        }
      });
    });
console.log(newArray);
```

**OR**

```
    var newArray = [];

        var singleArray = [].concat(...myArr);

        singleArray.forEach((val,key)=>{
          if(val.active)
          {
            newArray.push(val);
          }
        });

console.log(newArray);
```

I hope this will be useful.

Comment: Just wondering, is there a reason you use filter instead of foreach?

Answer (score 2):

First, I would flatten the array so each element can be on the same level and then just filter it.

It looks like this:

```
var activeProducts = myArr.flat().filter(item => item.active);
```

This solution is short and efficient but be careful the Array.prototype.flat method is not yet [supported on all browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=array-flat) but I'm sure you can find a polyfill.